# Razor Edit Function with the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building this Edit function that is using a modal in the UI. But I dont know I dont want a new View I want to use the Add View. Can I in the ActionResult  can I look for the index that is coming from the View?

View

```
 $(".references-list").on("click", ".edit-reference", function () {
            var index = $(this).data('index');
            console.log(index);

            getAjax("@Url.Action("Edit", index)", function (data, index)
            {
                $("#add-reference-modal .modal-body").html(data);
                $("#add-reference-modal").modal('show');
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Controllers

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string index)
    {

        return PartialView();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking how to pass a value to your controller?

Comment: I am trying to pass index but it is nul

Comment: should it be something like this "@Url.Action("Edit",index)" I get error that index doesnt exist

Comment: you can't set the value of a server side variable on the client side. @Url.Action is evaluated by the server then sent to the client. You're going to have to make a call to the action using javascript...are you trying to pass the url to the getAjax() function?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to pass the index value to the Controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass "index" to your controller like this:

```
        $(".references-list").on("click", ".edit-reference", function () {
        var index = $(this).data('index');
        console.log(index);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/myController/myAction/', //add your controler and action
            method: 'GET',
            data: { index : index }, // can be written as data: { index : $(this).data('index') }
            begin: function () {
                console.log('Ajax onBegin fired');
            },
            success: function (returnData) {
                console.log(returnData);
                //handle your modal
                //$("#add-reference-modal .modal-body").html(returnData);
                //$("#add-reference-modal").modal('show');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks billruhl Do I also need a view for edit? I have one for add that I would like to use?

Comment: That's up to you my friend. You can certainly use the same view for multiple things. Think about it, what is the difference between update / edit and create / add? Both operations usually have the same fields sans the record Id. You could just add a default id to the view and set it's value to 0 then only if the view is an edit form should the id be anything but 0...